# Which inputs could a neural network playing snake take?

Tags: neural-network

I'm developing a neural network learning to play snake using NeuroEvolution, however I don't know which inputs to give.

I tried giving only the position of the head of the snake and the position of the apple. Using this method the AI was able to reach scores of about 20, where it just went into its tail and died, because the tail isn't an input.

I'm not sure how to pass the tail as an input though without having an input for every pixel of the game.

Comment: If you want path-finding, you'll probably want 1 input per pixel/ simplified pixel (think blocks the width of your snake, say 10x10, with snake, apple, or empty as states, all treated as "one pixel", but this assumes your snake is locked in those boxes, if the snake is positioned per pixel, then per pixel is what you'll probably want). I don't know how you'd expect a neural network to do it with less information than a rules based AI.

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal I tried passing all simplified pixels, however the neural network didn't evolve at all because there were 225 (15 x 15) inputs to handle. I think a good result might be achieved by "looking" in some directions from the snake. I'm not sure how to implement that though.

Comment: Could you project "rays" of "looking" on the grid and give distance to wall and/or snake? What about doubling back... 

Or one input of a grid of the simplified pixels, treat it like image processing?

Maybe take a meta approach, send an input with a list of possible paths, and have it choose,. so all the path finding is done ahead. Maybe use a simple flood fill path find to find N paths, The idea being that it not pixels, but lists of movement. I'm not a Neural network guy, but I did game stuff and path stuff back in the day, so trying to think of options.

Comment: https://becominghuman.ai/designing-ai-solving-snake-with-evolution-f3dd6a9da867

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal Thanks, I think I'll try the method where the snake looks in certain directions and gives the distance to the tail, that should work.